# in memory database not reset auto increment column between tests even if DirtiesContext is set

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, junit

I have a test case which runs perfectly by itself (mvn -Dtest=MurexResponseOkTest test) but when running with other tests (mvn clean install) it always fail with jpa query error.

The error was raised because the auto increment column (ID column) was not reset to 1 between tests. For example,

mvn -Dtest=MurexResponseOkTest test will log

message body after save: = 1

message header after save: 1

markit trade event after save: 1

but mvn test will log:

message body after save: = 4

message header after save: 1

markit trade event after save: 2

I already have AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD set but it seems not working.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles({"boot", "test"})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have had similar  problem with Derby database. Solution was to add @Sql annotation and provide sql script that reset auto increment columns.